# Excel Formula for counting cells other than specific values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Trying to count number of fruits I have in column G, I have:

=COUNTIF(G:G,"Oranges") and =COUNTIF(G:G,"Mangoes")

How do I create a formula to calculate the rest? I mean all other fruits apart from Mangoes and Oranges in column G?

Comment: do you have a list, or is Excel supposed to guess?

Comment: Mangoes and Oranges are the most frequent ones whereas the rest are infrequent. Today could be strawberries and tomorrow apples. I am looking to create three counts. One for Mangoes, another for oranges and another for the remaining put all together.

I had in mind using (not equal to) <> "oranges" & "mangoes"

Comment: okay, `=COUNTA(G:G)-COUNTIF(G:G,"Oranges")-COUNTIF(G:G,"Mangoes")` you may need to adjust the references to exclude any titles in the ranges.

Comment: @ScottCraner - why not post as an answer? It's certainly the solution that occurred to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This solves the issue:*

- No need to use any extra column as Helper data used by @Erin.

[image]

- Formula in cell R2:

  `=COUNTIFS($O$2:$O$15,"<>Oranges",$O$2:$O$15,"<>Mangoes")`
- Formula in cell S2:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(--($O$2:$O$15<>"Oranges"),--($O$2:$O$15<>"Mangoes"))
  ```

**N.B.**

- To make formula dynamic instead of values you may use cell references.

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT(--($O$2:$O$15<>$P$2),--($O$2:$O$15<>$P$3))
  ```
- Where P2 & P3 comprises Oranges and Mangoes.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Comment: @Teodros IV glad to help you,,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 0):

Add a column all **1** in it.

Then use `=SUMIFS(F:F,G:G,"<>Oranges",G:G,"<>Mangoes")`

[image]

Comment: It's good one but can be achieved by COUNTIFS & SUMPRODUCT also ,, without the HELPER Data in Column F !!

Comment: Thank you very much Erin, much appreciated. However I am looking more into @RajeshS suggestion of not needing to create another column. Rajesh, could you please be kind enough to create one using either countifs or sumproducts without creating another column and leaving it at “0” if there are no values. Many thanks

Comment: @TeodrosIV ,now check my post this help you & keep asking ☺